# The ignite node is not starting up on windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file, ignite

I am trying to start an ignite grid node on Windows 7.
I have set the IGNITION_HOME env variable, pointing to the apache ignite 1.6 installation folder and I am using java 1.8, maven 3.3.9

Now when I try to run ignite.bat (in the bin folder of the installation directory) on the command prompt, I am getting the below error .

```
**The input line is too long.
goto :eof
:concat
set IGNITE_LIBS=%IGNITE_LIBS%;%1goto :eof was unexpected at this time.**
```

Looking at the error above, it looks like an issue with the bat file. I tried checking the bat file, but it seems to be fine.

It would be great if someone can point out what exactly I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your Ignite folder has a long path (like c:\my\deep\dir\structure\foo\bar), which causes the classpath to exceed Windows limit. Try to move Ignite to a dir with shorter path (like c:\ignite).

Answer (score 0):

Besides shortening the path as specified above, execute the command from within the bin directory (this worked for me). Use relative path for arguments:

```
 ignite.bat ..\examples\config\example-cache.xml
```

Should fire up without a problem.  Use this strategy for running the visor as well.